# is it a correct regex with have space and in between `some chancter`.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, regex, next.js

I am using this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss .

here user can select class uisng regex like this example `safelist: ['random', 'yep', 'button', /^nav-/]` so `/^nav/` is regex .I want add some regex  for this class

`.f20 [class*=" icn-"]:before` I tried like this `/* icn-/'` but it not works .can you please suggest where I am doing wrong .

Comment: `/ icn-/` will match anything that contains `" icn-"` so should be what you need. `*=` here is just a "contains" operator, it has a different meaning in the context of a regular expression.

Comment: what wil be the correct regex

Comment: Like I said, `/ icn-/` should be what you need.

Comment: \s is the regex representation for space, although the regex fill fail to detect the class if it's the first or unique class of an element

Comment: actually I am using json I thing it will give error .`{
  "plugins": [
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
    [
      "postcss-preset-env",
      {
        "autoprefixer": {
          "flexbox": "no-2009"
        },
        "stage": 3,
        "features": {
          "custom-properties": false
        }
      }
    ],
    [
      "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss",
      {
        "content": [
         
          
        ],
        safelist: ['rc10' ,'[class*=" icn-"]','/* icn-/','f20 [class*=" icn-"]:before',/ icn-/]
      }
  ]
]
}
`

Comment: I am confused now how to add `/ icn-/` in json file